# Reference a resource to be copied at build time

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio, I can add a resource (text file, image, etc.) to the project and have it copy to the output directory at build time. The problem with this is that the project copies the file into the project directory. I have a multi-project solution where many projects are referencing the same resource, I don't want the resource copied into every project directory. I want the resource to stay in a separate resource directory that I have under source control with the rest of the solution. Is there a way for me to add the resource to the projects and have the projects copy the resource to the debug and release directories on build that wouldn't force the file into the project directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In project explorer select the folder or project where you want to add the file and right click. Select `Add Existing Item` from menu.

Locate the file and click on the arrow near the `Add` button. From the menu opened, select `Add As Link`.

Do not forget to change the properties of the linked item (Copy To Output directory etc).

Comment: This is precisely what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to link the files into your projects instead of copying them.  See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306234 for steps.